Google Review Link Redirects to 404 on Samsung Devices Due to Auto-Appended "/mobile" in URL
I’m generating a Google review link using the following base URL:
https://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=<PLACE_ID>

For example:
https://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=ChIJo1AGxP8NkWsRhsybmuQdKQo&forceDesktop=true

This link works fine on both desktop and most mobile devices. However, on some Samsung devices, Google seems to automatically append /mobile to the URL, resulting in this URL:
https://search.google.com/local/writereview/mobile?placeid=ChIJo1AGxP8NkWsRhsybmuQdKQo

This modified URL leads to a 404 error. The original URL I generated works when /mobile is not added.
Here is my Laravel code that constructs and redirects to the Google Place URL if the google_place_id is found in my database:
public function handleCode($code)
{
    // Find the code in the database
    $codeRecord = Code::where('code', $code)->first();

    // Check if the code record is found
    if ($codeRecord && $codeRecord->is_attached == 1) {

        $codeRecord->total_scan += 1;
        $codeRecord->save();

        // Check if the business profile URL exists
        if (!empty($codeRecord->business_profile)) {
            // Redirect to the business profile URL
            return redirect($codeRecord->business_profile);
        } elseif (!empty($codeRecord->google_place_id)) {
            // Construct the Google Place URL using google_place_id
            $googlePlaceUrl = "https://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=" . $codeRecord->google_place_id;
            // Redirect to the Google Place URL
            return redirect($googlePlaceUrl);
        }
    }

    // If no code record is found or no URLs are found, redirect to register page
    return redirect('register');
}

The /mobile segment seems to be automatically appended on Samsung devices, causing a 404 error. How can I prevent or handle this behavior so the URL works consistently across all devices?
Any advice on how to handle this issue in Laravel would be greatly appreciated.
I tried generating a Google review link using the URL structure https://search.google.com/local/writereview?placeid=<PLACE_ID>, and it worked on desktop and most mobile devices. However, on some Samsung devices, Google automatically appends /mobile to the URL, which leads to a 404 error. I expected the link to work consistently across all devices without the /mobile part being added.
To troubleshoot, I confirmed that the original URL works when accessed directly on these devices. I also reviewed my Laravel code to ensure there were no conditions causing this, and I added &forceDesktop=true to prevent mobile redirection, but the issue persists on some Samsung devices.
